# How can I use mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk's StitchAppClientConfiguration in the browser's Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, browser, sdk

I tried to use the code to inform localAppNamelocal and localAppVersion in JavaScript, but I can't find any clear examples on the web. Can someone with knowledge about Stitch show us the correct one?

```
import {
    Stitch as Stitch,
    StitchAppClientConfiguration as StitchAppClientConfiguration
} from "mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk";

var ClientConfiguration = new StitchAppClientConfiguration.Builder().build()

ClientConfiguration.localAppName = 'My App'
ClientConfiguration.localAppVersion = '0.1'

Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient('myapp-cast', ClientConfiguration)
```

I tried to find it, but found nothing, not a clear example on the web or in the documentation.

Gratitude for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch-sdks/js/4/classes/stitchappclientconfiguration.builder.html#withlocalappname) entries associated with the respective sources, I arrived at the code above, tested it and returned the Object below in the Atlas Stitch panel. The correct version appeared in the connection control of client applications:

```
StitchAppClientConfiguration =
{ 
    "baseUrl":"undefined", 
    "storage":"undefined", 
    "dataDirectory":"undefined",
    "transport":"undefined", 
    "localAppName":"My App", 
    "localAppVersion":"0.1"
 }
```

Comment: Version is changed from Stich to Realm so this only solve legacy and died version